# How to leave out all NaNs a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm upgrading some code from python2 to python3 and the modern pandas version (I now have pandas 2.0.3 and numpy version 1.26.4)

My dataframe is :

```
        N  NE   E  SE   S  SW    W   NW
H12    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
H13    0.7 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0  1.4
H14    0.3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  0.8  1.1
H15    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
H16    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And I want to leave out all the NaNs such that i get a new df:

```
        N   W   NW
H13    0.7 1.0  1.4
H14    0.3 0.8  1.1
```

My old code has `df.any(1)` or something very similar used working, but now I get and error message

`NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Maybe there is a better way to do it, I'm not fussed about using `any()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) is now **keyword-only**, you have to use `axis=1`.

Although you have not shown your original code, the following should work:

```
out = df.loc[df.any(axis=1), df.any()]
```

Output:

```
       N    W   NW
H13  0.7  1.0  1.4
H14  0.3  0.8  1.1
```

Comment: Both work but I tick this one as you confirm my suspicion that the invocation of any() has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: if one needs new `df` then `df.dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1, how='all')` should suffice